# Hosting multiple ASP.NET Core 6 services within one Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service, c#-9.0

I've got multiple completely separate services which is create by "Tutorial: Create a minimal API with ASP.NET Core"
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Now,what I'd like to do is to run and stop them in a Windows Forms app. In addition how can I pass variable from my Windows Forms app to my services?

I try to change my `Program.cs` like a new class, is it correct ?

```
public class Program
{
    public WebApplication CreateService1()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share more details about your application structure and what variable you would like to pass?